# PHP - curl_multi_exec while loop uses 100% of the CPU

Tags: php

I'm getting data from multiple APIs using `curl_multi_exec`.

It uses a while loop to check to see if the data has come in. Since my server responds to the requests from multiple users simultaneously, I need to make sure this loop doesn't use 100% of the CPU.

So far, this is what I've tried:

```
<?php 
    // Build $mh the multi handle

    $running = null;
    do {
    curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
    curl_multi_select($mh);
    } while ($running);
?>
```

This post talks about `curl_multi_select`. Does this prevent it from using 100% of the CPU?
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-select.php

Comment: Alright. What about curl_multi_select($mh);?

Comment: check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69728824/php-multiple-curl-requests-curl-multi-speed-optimizations/69967511#69967511