# PHP - multiple curl requests curl_multi speed optimizations

Tags: php, api, curl

I'm using curl_multi to process multiple API requests in parallel.

However, I've noticed there is a lot of fluctuation in the time it takes to complete the requests.

Is this related to the speed of the APIs themselves, or the timeout I set on curl_multi_select? Right now it is 0.05. Should it be less? How can I know this process is finishing the requests as fast as possible without wasted time in between checks to see if they're done?

```
 <?php 

        // Build the multi-curl handle, adding each curl handle
        $handles = array(/* Many curl handles*/);

        $mh = curl_multi_init();
        foreach($handles as $curl){
            curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $curl);
        }
            
        $running = null;
        do {
            curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
            curl_multi_select($mh, 0.05); // Should this value be less than 0.05?
        } while ($running > 0);
      
        // Close the handles
        foreach($results as $curl){
            curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $curl);
        }
        curl_multi_close($mh);



?>
```

Comment: If there are running requests that timeout specifies how long to wait for a status update and is largely irrelevant unless you're doing something _other_ than checking the status in that loop. I would suggest leaving it at the default 1s as checking 20 times a second is approaching "busy wait loop" territory.

Comment: Aside from that the time it takes is dependent on how long it takes for those requests to complete. If a number of those requests are going to the same host, you might benefit from enabling pipelining which can reduce request overhead. If you are making large number of requests you might also have resource contention between them with the default "run all of them simultaneously" behaviour. All this and more being controlled by parameters that can be set with [`curl_multi_setopt()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-setopt.php)

Comment: The reason I check 20 times per second is because I am generating search results with my curl_multi. The default of 1s can cause a poor user experience. Thanks for your comment, I will check out the curl_multi_setopt stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

current implementation of `curl_multi_select()` in php doesn't block and doesn't respect timeout parameter, maybe it will be fixed later. the proper way of waiting is not implemented in your code, it have to be 2 loops, i will post some tested code from my bot as an example:

```
      $running  = 1;
      while ($running)
      {
        # execute request
        if ($a = curl_multi_exec($this->murl, $running)) {
          throw BotError::text("curl_multi_exec[$a]: ".curl_multi_strerror($a));
        }
        # check finished
        if (!$running) {
          break;
        }
        # wait for activity
        while (!$a)
        {
          if (($a = curl_multi_select($this->murl, $wait)) < 0)
          {
            throw BotError::text(
              ($a = curl_multi_errno($this->murl))
                ? "curl_multi_select[$a]: ".curl_multi_strerror($a)
                : 'system select failed'
            );
          }
          usleep($wait * 1000000);# wait for some time <1sec
        }
      }
```

Comment: Hi Michael this is very interesting. I didn't know curl_multi_select() doesn't block and doesn't respect timeout parameter. I tried your code out but it didn't work. Could you double check it for me? I really appreciate it. If I can get it to work I'll give you the check mark for the question

Comment: Michael, does this code work? I think it is doing the same thing you are

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-select.php#115381

Comment: @AlbertMcGloughn ye, it works, you may replace `yield` with `usleep($timeout * 1000000);` but it should be less than 1.0, because usleep may fail on larger values. also it has a problem with long polling but you dont have it right. it lacks top and bottoms where you
top: setup requests, add multi handles
bottom: check result with `curl_multi_info_read()` and remove handles

Answer (score -1):

doing

```
        $running = null;
        for(;;){
            curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
            if($running <1){
                   break;
            }
            curl_multi_select($mh, 1);
        }
```

should be better, then you'll avoid a useless select() when nothing is running..